# No Ads or Ad free?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm working on an app and wonder what is the best way to convey the message that the user won't have to watch another one for another three hours.

```
No Ads Until:
22 Dec 2020, 11:00
```

or

```
Ad Free Until:
22 Dec 2020, 11:00
```

Comment: It's "ad-free", with a hyphen, defined by [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ad-free) as "not containing any advertising".

Comment: Ad Free doesn't need to be hyphenated, although it can be: here's a New York Times headline "Netflix Is Ad Free, but It Isn’t Brand Free" https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/16/business/media/netflix-commercials.html

Comment: Either is fine; it's purely up to the writer's opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine for your purpose and will get the message across just fine. I would say "No ads until" sounds a little more natural.

You could also go with something a little more user friendly like "Next ad in 3 hours".

Side note: "Ad free" is not hyphenated in "Ad free until: ...". You'd only hyphenate it in "An ad-free app", "Your ad-free experience ends in 2 minutes".